# ruby regex pattern for shortcode syntax

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a ruby compatible regex that is able to find a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) string within text.

The regex would be able to identify the following strings:

- `[shortcode]`
- `[shortcode=value]`
- `[shortcode key=value]`
- `[shortcode=value]Text[/shortcode]`
- `[shortcode key1=value1 key2=value2]Text[/shortcode]`
- `[shortcode]Text[/shortcode]`

Comment: Please take the time to show samples of input and your expected results. Also show code you've written to solve this problem.

Comment: Do PHP and Ruby regexp syntax differ so much that it's difficult to translate from one to the other?

Comment: @KeithThompson yes they do.

Comment: @lukemh Fairly certain the regex provided in the [PHP question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346313/regex-pattern-for-shortcodes-in-php), previously indicated, works exactly the same for the given sample in Ruby as it does in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trimming down the solution provided in your example:

```
\[shortcode(.*?)\]((.*?)\[\/shortcode\])?
```

Where `$1` will get everything between the first `shortcode` and the nearest `]`, and `$3` will be the text between `[shortcode...]` and `[/shortcode]`.

As far as getting a list of parsed attributes of arbitrary length and order from a regex, no, you can't do it.  You might be able to look for a specific attributes in `$1` something like:

```
key=(.*?)\b
```

But to get the full list, you'll need to use other methods (perhaps the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) would help) to tokenize/parse `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
/\[(?<shortcode>([^\]]+))(.+?)?\](?:(.+?)?\[\/\k<shortcode>\])?/.match('[blah]whatever[/blah]')
# => #<MatchData "[blah]whatever[/blah]" shortcode:"blah">
```

(just replaced `$shortcode` by `(?<shortcode>([^\]]+))` inside the regexp of the link you gave and `\k<shortcode>` for the second one)